# Wald's equation for dependent decrements

Tags: algorithm-analysis, probability-theory

I'm taking a course on Coursera about approximation algorithms for fun and one of the modules uses probability to analyze the cost of a linear program with randomized rounding solution to the set cover problem.

One of the techniques employed is Wald's equation for dependent decrements, described in Neal Young's [Notes on algorithms](https://algnotes.info/on/background/stopping-times/walds-dependent/).

For Alice's coin-flipping example, can somebody please describe to me how $\delta$ is increasing if it's chosen to be $\delta(n_t) = \frac{1}{2} \lceil n_t \rceil$? As the number of coins left decreases doesn't $\delta(n_t)$ also decrease?

Clearly there's something missing in my understanding of how this works.

Comment: Note the statement of the theorem.  It mentions that $\delta$ is a monotonic function. Later it splits the statement into cases based, in particular, on whether $\delta$ is monotonically increasing or decreasing. In the example, $\delta(n_t) = n_t/2$ is an increasing function.

Comment: Please state the full problem here. I doubt many people will want to read the whole document you link, and links typically rot away.